# How to use sentry logging with multiple raven config

Tags: django, sentry, raven

Can I define multiple `RAVEN_CONFIG`s in my Django settings with different `dsn` values for them and then configure somehow so that when I get errors from files in one Django app, they get logged in one Sentry store and other Django app in another Sentry store?

Answer (score 2):

Try this way it worked

1) make custom handler of SentryHandler

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import logging

from raven.handlers.logging import SentryHandler


class CustomSentryHandler(SentryHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       dsn = kwargs.pop('dsn', None)

       self.tags = kwargs.pop('tags', None)

        logging.Handler.__init__(self, level=kwargs.get('level', logging.NOTSET))

        super(CustomSentryHandler, self).__init__(dsn, **kwargs)
```

2) Change your logging in settings

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': True,
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s '
                  '%(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'sentry1': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'class': 'project.sentry.CustomHandler',
        'dsn': '<DSN1>',
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'sentry1': {
        'handlers': ['sentry1'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': False,
    }
}
```

}

3) Log your errors

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('sentry2')
logger.error('yeey!')
```